# Robolectric: Error Inflating Layout when adding button to the layout.xml

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric version 1.1 and it can't run my test if there is a button in the activity.

**add_emoticon_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addEmoticonButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_emoticon_button_text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AddEmoticonActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AddEmoticonActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_emoticon_activity);
    }
}
```

**AddEmoticonActivityTest.java**

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import android.widget.Button;

import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowToast;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AddEmoticonActivityTest {
    private AddEmoticonActivity addEmoticonActivity;
    private Button addButton;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        addEmoticonActivity = new AddEmoticonActivity();
        addEmoticonActivity.onCreate(null);
        addButton = (Button) addEmoticonActivity.findViewById(R.id.addEmoticonButton);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDisplayErrorMessageWhenEmptyContentAdded() {
        addButton.performClick();

        ShadowHandler.idleMainLooper();
        assertThat(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast(), equalTo(addEmoticonActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.no_content_error_message)));
    }
}
```

Below is the stacktrace that I got when I ran the test

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error inflating layout/add_emoticon_activity
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:106)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:82)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:86)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.inflateView(ResourceLoader.java:377)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:43)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:48)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivity.onCreate(AddEmoticonActivity.java:10)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivityTest.setup(AddEmoticonActivityTest.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.constructView(ViewLoader.java:228)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.create(ViewLoader.java:179)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.inflate(ViewLoader.java:150)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.inflate(ViewLoader.java:153)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:102)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:82)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:86)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.inflateView(ResourceLoader.java:377)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:43)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:99)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:111)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:99)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:111)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivity.onCreate(AddEmoticonActivity.java:10)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivityTest.setup(AddEmoticonActivityTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ColorResourceLoader.getValue(ColorResourceLoader.java:33)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.getColorValue(ResourceLoader.java:382)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getColor(ShadowResources.java:65)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.setBackgroundColor(ShadowView.java:243)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowButton.applyAttributes(ShadowButton.java:14)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.__constructor__(ShadowView.java:90)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.__constructor__(ShadowView.java:82)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.constructView(ViewLoader.java:228)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.create(ViewLoader.java:179)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.inflate(ViewLoader.java:150)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader$ViewNode.inflate(ViewLoader.java:153)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:102)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:82)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ViewLoader.inflateView(ViewLoader.java:86)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.res.ResourceLoader.inflateView(ResourceLoader.java:377)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:43)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLayoutInflater.inflate(ShadowLayoutInflater.java:48)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.setContentView(ShadowActivity.java:101)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivity.onCreate(AddEmoticonActivity.java:10)
    at com.erlanggatjhie.emotextcon.activities.AddEmoticonActivityTest.setup(AddEmoticonActivityTest.java:24)
    ... 20 more
```

If I remove the button from layout.xml, it will work beautifully.

Does anyone know what happened?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it all comes down the a NullPointerException that caused the original problem.

This commit happened after 1.1 was released and it changed line 33 of the ColorResourceLoader.java, which is the line where you received the error.

https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/commit/f647512bd80162f9cb6b2fac8c7b0db984266967

It looks like if you upgrade to a newer version of Robolectric it may fix the problem.  I know 1.1 is the latest release version, but there is a [2.0 alpha 1](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/01/robolectric-20-alpha-1.html) version that is out.

Comment: I upgraded into 2.0-alpha and it works. I don't know what's happening with 1.1 though. Thanks for your suggestion